# how to judge a text file or binary file using Java language in Windows environment?

Tags: java, file, text, binary

I am counting the total number of text files, and there are lots of files in a folder including text files and other binary files.

How do I judge if the file is text file or binary files using Java language?

Comment: You can look at the name extension.  Or you can use an heuristic -- read the file assuming UTF8 or whatever and see if any bytes don't fit the mold.

Answer (score 0):

If you're talking about plain text, what characters are in a text file ?
9 (tab), 10 (line feed), 13 (carriage return), 32 to 126 (readable characters)

A text file should have a near-100% ratio of char in this set.

On the other hand, binary files use the whole set of char, and so should have lower ratio. Also, binaries usually contain a lot of 0 values.

It is not a 100% sure way to determine file type, but I think it should be enough.